# Crop dynamically signature images

Tags: java, image, wacom

Im developing a java application that captures client signatures from Wacom USB tablet, creates a 320x200 pixels white background image with signature and stores into database, to print it on PDF later.

Before saving them, I would like to crop that images over signature. I mean, one client can sign on the left zone in the tablet and another one on the right zone. So all signatures would have different positions in the signature image and useless white space. For example, [different signature images](https://gyazo.com/112320feb830d9cf0be7fa175a0d49ac) and I would like something like [this](https://gyazo.com/0a9c63a2fc6060a57e788d85c0fb0b70)

So my question is, is this possible? Is there any option to crop these images dynamically over signature before save it? Knowing all signatures have different size can't crop always from same positions. Or would be better, for example, to print a rectangle in the tablet forcing clients to sign inside it? (Don't know is this would be possible, I suppose yes).

Thanks.

Comment: You could start by analyzing the image on a pixel-by-pixel basis. Construct an empty `Rectangle`. For every pixel in the image (iteration order doesn't matter) add that coordinate to the rectangle if it's not white. This is incidentally ideally parallelizable with Java 8 streams. I like this challenge so if you can wait ~6 hours I can brew up an example at home.

Comment: Sure @MarkJeronimus, would appreciate it. I like your idea, mine was something like yours, but didn't even know from where to start. And no worries, I can wait as long as necessary :) Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language are u using?
x0=10000,y0=10000;x1=0,y1=0
iteratate over all pixels (x,y) in the image and if a pixel is "set" do
x1=max(x,x1); y1=max(y,y1); x0=min(x0,x); y0=min(y0;y);
after the iteration you have the rectancle x0,y0 to y1,y1 to crop the image.

Comment: @TomB Hi Tom, Im using Java. I'll check your answer, thanks :)

Comment: If you need readymade software that does exactly what you are trying to do (support wacom, produce signed pdfs, etc.) feel free to have a look at www.is2.de/insign (we are the maker of inSign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Cropper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://www.citrix.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Signature-Richard1.jpg"));
        int x0=src.getWidth();
        int y0=src.getHeight();
        int x1=0;
        int y1=0;
        //just a guess: the pixels color at 0,0 is wht you want to crop
        int unusedcolor=src.getRGB(0,0);
        //iterate over all pixels
        for (int y = 0; y < src.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < src.getWidth(); x++) {
                  int  clr   = src.getRGB(x, y);
                  if (clr!=unusedcolor)
                  {
                      //pixel is used, shift the new borders accordingly 
                      x0=Math.min(x0, x);
                      y0=Math.min(y0, y);
                      x1=Math.max(x1, x);
                      y1=Math.max(y1, y);
                  }
            }
        }
        if (x1>x0 && y1>y0)
        {
            BufferedImage dest = src.getSubimage(x0, y0, x1-x0,y1-y0);
            ImageIO.write(dest, "png", new File("out.png"));
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start out.png");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I adapted your code to my program and is working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I promised a parallel stream approach. Here it is.

Uncropped image (png): http://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png"));

    BufferedImage sigImage = cropSignature(img);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(sigImage)));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    });
}

private static BufferedImage cropSignature(BufferedImage img) {
    // Iterating over height has better CPU cache performance.
    Rectangle sigRect = IntStream.range(0, img.getHeight())
                                 .parallel()
                                 .mapToObj(y -> getHorizontalSpan(img, y))
                                 .collect(() -> new Rectangle(0, 0, -1, -1),
                                          (r1, r2) -> r1.add(r2),
                                          (r1, r2) -> r1.add(r2));

    return img.getSubimage(sigRect.x, sigRect.y, sigRect.width, sigRect.height);
}

private static Rectangle getHorizontalSpan(BufferedImage img, int y) {
    // Don't parallelize. The 'combiner' is therefore not necessary and may be null.
    return IntStream.range(0, img.getWidth())
                    .filter(x -> isSignatureColor(img.getRGB(x, y)))
                    .collect(() -> new Rectangle(0, 0, -1, -1),
                             (r, x) -> r.add(x, y),
                             null);
}

private static boolean isSignatureColor(int rgb) {
    // Easiest criteria, but fails on JPG files because it doesn't use a tolerance. 
    return rgb != -1;
}
```